# Pass 2 different data types with jQuery to HttpHandler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to pass 2 data types to the HttpHandler in a Webhandler

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "FileHandler.ashx",
    contentType:false,
    processData: false,
    data: {
        data: newData,
        pathname:"~/pathname/"
    }, 
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was error uploading files!");
    }
});
```

The `RequestPayload` in the POST is [object object], is there documentation on how I can parse that object?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Create a new  model with all the props including the pathname prop

```
public class HandlerModel
{
 public datatype dataprop1 {get;set;} 
 public datatype dataprop2 {get;set;} 
 public datatype dataprop3 {get;set;} 
 public datatype dataprop4 {get;set;} 
 public string pathname {get;set;}
}
```

then  in your ashx file

```
public class QueryStringHandler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {

 //set the content type, you can either return plain text, html text, or json or other type    
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        //deserialize the object
        UserInfo objUser = Deserialize<HandlerModel>(context);

        //now we print out the value, we check if it is null or not
        if (objUser != null) {
            context.Response.Write("Go the Objects");
        } else {
            context.Response.Write("Sorry something goes wrong.");
        }
}

public T Deserialize<T>(HttpContext context) {
        //read the json string
        string jsonData = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        //cast to specified objectType
        var obj = (T)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonData);

        //return the object
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am transferring pdf's and images, what data type would that cast as?

Comment: now that will make it complex. Didn't knew you were passing pdf file i advice you to pass the location of pdf and read it in webhandlers usually pdf and image file can be stored in byte of array byte[]  this artical may help you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/save-and-read-pdf-file-using-sql-server-and-C-Sharp/